# Get the result number inside foreach and while

Tags: php, database

Since my english is not very good, I want to apologize first if my question is unclear. 
My code was like this:

```
$word = explode(' ',$abstract); // <== explode('space',$abstract)
foreach($word as $word){

  $KMP = new KMP(); 

  $b = mysqli_query("select * from my_table");
  while($text = mysqli_fetch_array($b)){

    if($word!=''){
      $result = $KMP->KMPSearch($word,$text['$abstract']);
      echo "Result Words : ".$word."<br/>";
      echo "Result Words in number : ".count($result)."<br/>";
      echo "On String : ";
      foreach($result as $h) echo $h." ";
      echo "<br/>";
    }

    echo "<div style='width:600px;'>";
    echo "<h3>".$text['title']."</h3><hr/>";
    echo nl2br(str_replace($word,"<font color='red'>".$word."</font>",$text['abstract']));
    echo "</div>";
  }
}
```

The output of this code was like this:

```
TITLE HERE
```

Output of the abstract that tell us about **virus**

```
Result Words : **virus**
Result Words in Number : 1    
On String : 43
```

Because while loop inside foreach `$word` so it searched per each word in `my_table`. So it will be looped like this:

```
TITLE HERE
```

**Output** of the abstract that tell us about virus

```
Result Words : **output**    
Result Words in Number : 1    
On String : 0

TITLE HERE
```

Output of the **abstract** that tell us about virus

```
Result Words : **abstract**    
Result Words in Number : 1    
On String : 15

TITLE HERE
```

Output of the abstract that tell us about **virus**

```
Result Words : **virus**    
Result Words in Number : 1    
On String : 43
```

The result that I wanted was that result words in number.

If the cases were like above, the result was 3 words were found.

```
if ($result<5)
{
  //upload has been granted
}
elseif ($result>=5)
{
  //can't upload
}
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: i got my answer now after trial and error, if someone wants to know the answer just message me.

Comment: Mas, I wanna know the answer.  If you don't mind please send me the code. cleo1patria@gmail.com

Comment: @Jokurilisme if you found the answer yourself, please post it as an answer. You will be able to further accept it after a couple of days indicating that it solved your problem. Best regards